# is it possible to connect to internet from one remote system

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008, lan, internet

I have a query to know if it is possible to get connected to internet from a remote system . This means that suppose there are three computers A,B,C. the system A is connected to internet(lets say via internet dongle from a USB port) and all the three systems A,B and C are connected VIA LAN. So if dongle is connected to system A then can i browse from system B and System C.

Comment: All current operating systems offer some funcionality for this. How it's done exactly and how it is called depends on the OS. As an example, with Windows it's called Internet Connection Sharing.

Comment: @SvW i tried with windows internet sharing and it does not work

Comment: "I tried it and it didn't work" is not at all anything that could be used to help you fix your problem. But really, this question is off-topic here ([SF] is for pro admins only, see the [FAQ]). If you heavily improve the question, it might fit on [SU], but search their archive and their FAQ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.  Assuming Windows, the feature is called "Internet Connection Sharing."

As excerpted from [the Microsoft article describing how](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/using-ics-internet-connection-sharing):

> To enable ICS, on your host computer:
>
> Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the
>   Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet,
>   clicking Network and Sharing Center, and then clicking Manage network
>   connections.
>
> Right-click the connection that you want to share, and then click
>   Properties. Administrator permission required If you are prompted for
>   an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or
>   provide confirmation.
>
> Click the Sharing tab, and then select the Allow other network users
>   to connect through this computer’s Internet connection check box.

Basically this turns your computer into a router.  All routers have 2 interfaces, one is "WAN", the other is "LAN."  The interface you just enabled ICS on is the "WAN" interface.

Assuming you are using a 3G USB dongle for Internet, your system hopefully has a wired Ethernet port.  This is going to be your "LAN" interface - you will need to connect a small 4 or 8 port switch to this port, and then the rest of your computers to this switch.  The computers will then be using the ICS computer as a DHCP server and router.

Your "LAN" interface can also be a Wifi interface associated to an access point that is NOT doing DHCP or routing (I know you can specifically disable DHCP and routing on DD-WRT flashed routers but I'm not sure about routers with factory firmware.) - any other machine that connects to the access point should be able to use the Internet through the ICS system.  You could also connect your computer's wired connection to the WAN port of the wireless router and it may work.